# How to open multiple webpages from org mode?

Tags: org-mode, web-browser

I have a list of www addresses as a list like:

```
- https://www.nytimes.com
- https://www.foxnews.com
```

and so on. I can open single elements with the command `org-open-at-point` which is bound to the key sequence <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-o</kbd>. A Firefox tab will open on the correct address.

However, how could I mark a list and open all of them each on a single tab?

Answer (score 2):

The following lisp code lets `org-open-at-point` open all links within the active region. It behaves like the original version if region is not active.

If you want to use the code paste it in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) and re-start emacs.

```el
(defun orgTZA-open-at-point-ad (oldfun &rest args)
  "Just `org-open-at-point'.
If region is active open all links in region."
  (if (use-region-p)
      (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (progn
           (org-next-link)
           (null org-link-search-failed))
        (apply oldfun args))))
    (apply oldfun args)))

(advice-add #'org-open-at-point :around #'orgTZA-open-at-point-ad)
```

Comment: While this works (thanks for that!), it is slow in Emacs 28.2, waiting ~2-4 seconds after opening each link in Firefox 108.0.1 before opening the next (at least on Ubuntu 22.04). Any idea how to speed up?

Answer (score 1):

Org mode can to this natively:

```
* Some heading
- [[https://www.nytimes.com][link 1]]
- [[https://www.foxnews.com][link 2]]
```

Do `C-c C-o RET` on the heading, it will open the two pages on the default browser.